# How to get the total length of all strings in an ArrayList<String>?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

If I use an example for this question, it is very simple to understand:

```
ArrayList<String> array;
String str = toString(array);

String toString(ArrayList<String> array) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for( String string : array ) {
        sb.append(string);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The question is:
How to get `str`'s length efficiently without converting the `array` to string explicitly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
int length = 0;
for(String str : array){
  length += str.length();
}
```

Comment: You guys were faster than me!

Answer (score 11):

```
int length = 0;
for (String str : array) {
    length += str.length();
}
```

Comment: Hahaha, every character is the same as my answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate through the `ArrayList<String>` and adding the length of each element

Answer (score 1):

Adding a recursive variant just for fun...

```
public static int length(List<String> list) {
    if (list.size() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return list.get(0).length() + length(list.subList(1, list.size()));
}
```

Maybe not the most efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

```java
int length = array.stream().mapToInt(String::length).sum();
```